# Add or remove a behavior in Polymer 1.0 on runtime

Tags: runtime, polymer-1.0, behavior

It is possible add or remove a behavior in Polymer 1.0 on runtime?

Suppose `myBehavior1` and `myBehavior2` contains different implementation of method `methodBehavior()`;

i want something like this:

```
  Polymer({
        is: 'my-element',

        behaviors: [myBehavior.myBehavior1],

        _method: function(something){
              if (something == 'anotherThing'){
                    this.push('behaviors', myBehavior.myBehavior2)
              }
              this.methodBehavior()
        },
  });
```

but not works: myBehavior2 is added but the new implementation of the method (this.methodBehavior()) isn't used.